# Why does the reaction between Na (s) and Cl2 (g) occur spontaneously if the entropy of the system decreases?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, entropy

1- The reaction is exothermic.
2- My book says that it is because the total entropy change is very positive. 
Here is my book's explanation and it is the highlighted part which i dont understand :
"Despite the fact that there is a decrease in the entropy of the system, the energy leaving the system produces a substantial increase in the entropy of the surroundings, because **there are more ways of arranging the energy quanta in the rest of the universe than there are of arranging them in the system alone**.

Comment: The book is correct. Spontaneity is governed by the change in entropy of the universe which is the sum of the change in entropy of the system and the change in entropy of the surroundings. The change in entropy of the surroundings is derived from the enthalpy change of the system.

Comment: @Zhe  okay what i didnt understand is what i wrote in bold. So what if there are more ways of arranging the energy quanta in the rest of the universe than there are of arranging them in the system alone?

Comment: That's the definition of entropy...

Comment: @Zhe  i think i got it. It is because there will be a smaller chance of having the energy quanta divided equally over the molecules in the surroundings right ?

Comment: "It is because there will be a smaller chance of having the energy quanta divided equally over the molecules in the surroundings" Not sure what that means... The number of microstates available in the surroundings per unit increase in energy is larger. That is the definition of entropy.

Comment: @Zhe  yeah never mind what i said in that comment but here is what i am thinking of now : energy is gained by the surroundings. Now the entropy of the surroundings is greater because there are more ways of sharing the energy quanta between the particles in the surroundings than there was which means that there is a less chance of the particles in the surroundings having equal amounts of energy. But why did the book compare the number of ways in which the energy quanta could arrange themselves in the universe , with the number of possible arrangements in the system ?

Comment: The count in the system decreases. The count in the surrounding is increases. The total for the universe increases because the surroundings' increase is larger. Also, be careful, but entropy works on density of states, not raw state count...

Comment: @Zhe  Sorry for not being clear when i explained my idea. I will try to make it more simple now. Lets imagine that all the energy is transferred to the molecules in the air (not to anything else). The surroundings now contain more quanta of energy than before, and all these quanta(s) are contained within the molecules in the air. An ordered arrangement would mean that these molecules are stacked together and not moving and all these molecules possess the same amount of quanta. Now what i understood is that there are more quanta of energy in the surroundings

Comment: @Zhe  (continued) , so that there are more possible ways of sharing these quanta(s) of energy between the molecules. More ways of sharing these quanta(s) means that there is a less chance that each molecule will have the exact same amount of quanta. But why did they compare the number of ways of arranging the energy quanta in the surroundings with the number of ways the energy quanta can be arranged in the system ?

Comment: Max white: While writing [an answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/80359/45298) to [that analogous question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19899/45298), I suddenly had the idea how to answer your question easily and without obvious paradoxes. Perhaps you are interested to read the radically  [new edit of my answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/78740/45298).

Answer (score 3):

As you point out there are two things to consider, the heat released in the reaction and the change in entropy. In forming NaCl from chlorine gas and solid sodium the entropy decreases because the gas is converted into solid NaCl which has a far far smaller total volume. The energy released has the effect of heating the solid NaCl just formed and then the surroundings as energy flows away to eventually reach equilibrium again but now at a higher temperature than that at equilibrium before reaction occurred.

When a quantity of heat $dq$ from a body at $T_2$ transfers to one at $T_1$ the overall entropy change is $dS = dS_1 + dS_2 = dq/T_1 - dq/T_2$. As $T_2 \gt T_1$ the entropy change is positive.

In the reaction the entropy change overall depends on comparing that decreased due to volume decrease vs. that increased due to the energy released on reaction.

Entropy is a measure of the number of ways that the particles can be placed into their energy levels, this is often called the number of configurations $\Omega$, and Boltzmann found that $S=k\ln(\Omega)$ so that increasing the distribution of energy into the energy levels increases $\Omega$ and hence *S*. As the temperature increases more vibrational and rotational levels are populated and the kinetic energy distribution widens, all this means that there is an increased number of configurations and hence entropy just because energy can be placed into  energy levels and in more ways.

If there was just one level then all 'particles' would have to be in this level and so entropy would be zero, $\Omega=1$.  When there are two levels some can be in the first and some in the second level and now the entropy is increased ($\Omega \gt 1$), and so on for many levels.

Comment: So the released energy increases the entropy of the surroundings because there are more possible arrangements of energy quanta which means that there is a lesser chance of the particles being in the same energy level, right ?

Comment: yes, just so, entropy interpreted at a molecular level is all about the *number of ways* a molecule's energy can be distributed among its energy levels.

Answer (score 1):

> "...there are more ways of arranging the energy quanta in the rest of the universe than there are of arranging them in the system alone."

This sentence is poetical gibberish if one does not first study the
chemical reaction at hand by the fundamental equation.

#### 1 Prelininary remarks

Because of [his question about statistical mechanics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/78683/45298), I suppose that the questioner has (at least superficial) knowledge of the fundamental equation of (chemical) thermodynamics $\ce{\Delta G} = \Delta H – {T\Delta S}$, otherwise it would be nearly impossible to explain the touched entanglement without gibberish.

In the formation reaction of $\ce{NaCl}$ from the elements, $\ce{\Delta G}$ is negative if the amount of (negative) $\Delta H$ (exothermic reaction) exceeds the amount of (positive) $\ce{–T\Delta S}$; this is the indication that this reaction may proceed spontaneously. If during the reaction, the punctual temperature near the piece of sodium in the porcelain boat is “relatively low” (perhaps 1000°C, when chlorine is channeled *slowly* over the sodium), the positive value of $\ce{–T\Delta S}$ does not exceed $\Delta H$.

#### 2 The core argument

While it is otherwise a good practical jingle, this antagonistic view of $\Delta H$ and ${T\Delta S}$ is confusing if one tries to apply it (as in the question) from the point of view of the law of increasing entropy. Entropy is defined as $\Delta  
S$ = $\frac{\Delta q}{T}$ (where q is transferred “heat” $\Delta H$). The real meaning of $\ce{\Delta G}$ may only be revealed if it is transformed into its entropy representation, by dividing the fundamental equation by (-T) (note that $\Delta H$ and $\Delta S$ are by definition $\Delta H_{sys}$ and ${\Delta S}_{sys}$):

$$\ce{-\frac{\Delta G}{T}} = -\frac{\Delta H_{sys}}{T} + {\Delta S}_{sys}$$

In this equation $\frac{\Delta H_{sys}}{T}$ is the entropy change of the system by “heat” exchange with the surroundings, hence $\frac{\Delta H_{sys}}{T} = -\Delta S_{surroundings}$. On this basis, the above equation may be identified as:

$$\Delta S_{total} = {\Delta S_{surroundings} + \Delta S}_{sys}$$

$\Delta S_{sys}$ and $\Delta S_{surroundings}$ strive mutually to a maximum of $\Delta S_{total}$.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it looks like you are struggling with the base concept of spontaneity.

Spontaneity is characterized by having the total entropy change in a process be non-negative:

$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{universe}} \geq 0$$

This we can decompose into two pieces:

$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{universe}} = \Delta S_{\mathrm{surroundings}} + \Delta S_{\mathrm{system}}\geq 0$$

So, the system or the surroundings can experience a decrease in entropy as long as the other component more than compensates for the decrease with an increase in entropy that is at least as large as the decrease.

The definition of entropy is:
$$S = k \log \Omega$$ where $\Omega$ is the density of states, that is the number of states available for some small increase in energy:

$$\Omega = \frac{\delta \Phi}{\delta E}$$

The bold statement is trying to say that because the "number of states" (even though they mean density of states) is decreasing in the system, the entropy change is negative. On the other hand, because of the high exothermicity of reaction, the density of states in the surroundings is increasing by an amount that more than compensates for this (i.e., the entropy of the surroundings goes up a lot). This maintains the overall relationship that $\Delta S_{\mathrm{universe}}\geq 0$ even though the system's entropy change is negative.

Specifically, in your reaction, the increase in entropy of the surroundings is derived from the massive quantity of heat that you're dissipating from the system.

Comment: Okay i understood what you just said in this answer but what i dont understand is what i wrote in bold. Did i write something wrong in the last two comments ?

Comment: @Maxwhite No, the comments were getting long, and I thought I understood your problem, but maybe not. I'm having trouble understanding what about the bold statement you don't understand...

Comment: The thing is that i dont see why they even mentioned the number of possible arrangements of quanta in the system. They are explaining why the energy leaving the system produces an increase in the entropy of the surroundings right ? If i had to explain why that energy increases the entropy of the surroundings i would say : After the energy has been transferred to the surroundings, there are more possible arrangements of quanta in the universe. If we thought of the "universe" as the gas molecules in the air, this transfer of energy to the surroundings means that now there is a smaller chance of

Comment: (Continued) the molecules sharing their quanta equally since there are more possible arrangements and only one of these arrangements has all the quanta shared equally between the molecules. Now, is my explanation correct ?

Comment: @Maxwhite Updated answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay now i think we are talking about two different points because i understood what you said but it is not what i am talking about. Look, they said "the energy leaving the system produces a substantial increase in entropy of the surroundings because,". They want to explain how the energy released increases the entropy of the surroundings. Not why the reaction is spontaneous even though the entropy of the system decreases (i understand why it is spontaneous). So we are only discussing how this released energy increases the entropy of the surroundings.

Comment: And what i dont understand is : what does the entropy change of the system have to do with the way the released energy increases the entropy of the system. Is my explanation for the way in which the released energy increases the entropy of the surroundings (in the previous comment) correct ?

Comment: The released energy does not have anything to do with the entropy of the system, only the entropy of the surroudings.

Comment: Dude please i just need to know if the explanation that i wrote in response to your answer is correct (about how the energy released increases the entropy of the surroundings).

Comment: Ugh. You've written so much now that I can't tell what is what... :(

Comment: There is a little inaccuracy in your post, the $\Omega$ you use is the number of configurations not the density of states, which is just the number of levels/unit energy (and so has dimensions  1/energy). The $\Omega$ is the number of ways of placing *N* molecules  into its energy levels so that $n_1$ are in level 1, $ n_2$ in level 2 and so on then $\Omega = N!/(n_1!n_2!\cdots)$

Comment: Ok lol ... I was talking about the explanation which i wrote right before your comment "Updated answer. Hope this helps."

Comment: @porphyrin Yes, wrong term. It's the number of states within $\delta E$.

Comment: @Maxwhite You're looking for the derivation of $\Delta S$ for entropy of surroundings. We're using $dS = \frac{q}{T}$ to compute this value from the enthalpy change of the system.

Comment: @Zhe I still think that its wrong, (1) $\Omega$ its the total number of configurations  and (2) your density of states its wrong dimensionally as the log has to be dimensionless. The density of states is just how many energy levels there are /energy gap,  not the number of ways  particles are placed into these levels which is $\Omega$

Comment: @porphyrin No, we're saying the same thing. $\Omega$ is not the density. It is the number of states within $\delta E$ of $E$, i.e. $\omega(E)\delta E$.

Comment: @zhe still don't agree; as in my previous comment the number of states in any energy interval is not important because if the temperature is zero then only one state is populated out of all the thousands of them  and entropy is zero . It is the number of ways of arranging the energy among the states that counts. If you want to calculate the extra entropy then  start with $\Omega =N!/(n_1!\cdots n_i!)$ , remove one from $n_1$ and add it to state $n_i$  and recalculate $\Omega'=N!/((n_1-1)\cdots  (!n_i+1)\cdots)$ , take logs of both and find $\delta S= -k\ln(n_i/n_1)$ when $n\gg 1$

Comment: @porphyrin For example, see: http://www.harding.edu/lmurray/themo_files/notes/ch09.pdf

Comment: @Zhe, yes its interesting but very unintuitive. His $\Omega(E)$ is the number of microstates which he then maximises (page 9 and eqn 44), this is just the same as my $\Omega$. He defines his $\Omega(E)=w (E)\delta(E)$ with $w(E)$ as density of states and then finds from this the number of microstates that are most probable; again just the same as the $\Omega$ I used. (Your $\Phi$ is the number of accessible states and the number of states at E is $\Omega=(d\Phi/dE)\delta(E)$, then from this the max number accessible microstates is found. You skip too many steps when you define your $\Omega$.

Comment: I think I've just gotten used to the statement right after equation 9.41...